# Scala - Ordering fails for PriorityQueue

Tags: scala, priority-queue

I am trying to create a simple priority queue in Scala:

```
val priorities: mutable.PriorityQueue[Priority] = mutable.PriorityQueue(
 Priority(2, 302),
 Priority(3, 300),
 Priority(5, 400),
 Priority(4, 309),
 Priority(1, 301)
)(Ordering.by[Priority, Int](_.priority).reverse)

case class Priority(priority: Int, value: Int)
```

And when I do
`priorities.foreach(p => println(p.priority, p.value))`

The output I expect is:

```
(1,301)
(2,302)
(3,300)
(4,309)
(5,400)
```

But instead, I get:

```
(1,301)
(2,302)
(5,400)
(4,309)
(3,300)
```

As you can see, there is some problem with the ordering. Can I please get some insights about where I am going wrong and what shall I do to get the desired output?

Comment: From scaladoc:

Only the dequeue and dequeueAll methods will return elements in priority order. Standard collection methods including drop, iterator, and toString will remove or traverse the heap in whichever order seems most convenient.

Therefore, printing a PriorityQueue will not reveal the priority order of the elements, though the highest-priority element will be printed first. To print the elements in order, one must duplicate the PriorityQueue (by using clone, for instance) and then dequeue them:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foreach` method processes all the elements of the `PriorityQueue` but not necessarily in the sorted order. If you remove the elements you can see that the ordering is working:

```
while (priorities.nonEmpty) println(priorities.dequeue())

Priority(1,301)
Priority(2,302)
Priority(3,300)
Priority(4,309)
Priority(5,400)
```

The implementation keeps the first element as the highest priority element but the remainder are unsorted. `dequeue` will bring the new highest priority element to the front.

There does not appear to be a non-destructive way to show the whole `PriorityQueue` in order.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing out that simply iterating over a PriorityQueue won't give me the order. I just wanted to use this as a Min_heap. Thanks a ton.